# Will multi threading help performance improvement in creating text files in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I want to generate a output text file and the inputs are taken from the Database. The database is huge and there are lots of condition needs to be checked on creating every part of the output text file. So, its a bit time consuming process.

Will multi threading help improving the performance of the rails application?

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading *may* help improving the performance of the rails application, but it depends a little on the Ruby version you're running on. With MRI Ruby you'll only get improvements when doing lots of I/O operations (reading from the database, writing something to disk, ...).
The condition checks will not be run in parallel because of the global interpreter lock.

However when you're using Rubinius 2 or JRuby you'll get ruby interpreters that don't have a global interpreter lock and are therefore capable of doing the condition checks in parallel using threads.

In the end it will also depend on your implementation and requirements (is it even possible to do all the checks in parallel or are there dependencies etc.)

Comment: Benedikt, I do have lots I/O operations(query database) but all this query I fire at first and get in instance variables. So, will using multi threading useful in this case?. Is there any better approach to improve performance in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no simple answer to that. You'll have to analyze the overall performance of the queries and condition checks. What's the bottleneck and if you have done everything to improve the performance. Try doing less queries, add database indexes, try doing the fastest checks first, try moving some checks into the database query and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo that multithreading *may* help.  The simplest way to tell is to run 'top' while your program is running.  If one cpu core is pegged at 100% and the other is idle, you probably would benefit from either multiple threads or multiple processes.  That's the obvious case though - if it's not so clear, you have to dig further and identify the bottleneck.

Comment: Dave, while running the task the two cpu usage goes something like this.                                                            CPU1-80,84,82,84,66,54                                               CPU2-60,50,40,40,70,50                                                As I mentioned earlier, I need to check many conditions during the process. All these conditions are not dependent but I'm carrying all this sequentially. Is it possible to do this parallel?. As Ruby has GIL, will multi threading help checking conditions in different threads?

Comment: Are you running the ruby process and the DB on the same box?  If not, what is using the other core while your process is running?

Comment: Yes Dave, I'm running Ruby process and DB in same box.

Comment: Sounds like your first order of business is moving the DB to another box.  At that point you may see benefits from multiple threads or multiple processes.  From the top %'s you posted, it looks like you're nearly CPU-bound presently, so you might have some marginal improvement, but it won't be a big win since the DB is using the other core (and fairly heavily at that).